# PHP - POST form will not pass numeric value for checkbox, but accepts all other values

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

```
$squery = $cbdbc->prepare("SELECT * from sitedata");
$squery->execute();
while ($srow = $squery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($rresult[$srow['siteName']] !== $srow['siteID']) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' name='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' value='" . $srow['siteID'] . "'><label for='".$srow['siteID']."'>" . str_replace('_',' ',$srow['siteName']) . "</label></td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' name='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' value='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' checked='checked'><label for='".$srow['siteID']."'>" . str_replace('_',' ',$srow['siteName']) . "</label></td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Submit'></td></tr></table></form>";} elseif (null !== filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'setromstores')) {
$rid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'setromstores');
$squery = $cbdbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM sitedata");
$squery->execute();
while ($srow = $squery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $sid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, (string)$srow['siteID']);
    if ($sid !== null) {
        $uquery = $cbdbc->prepare("UPDATE roms SET " . $srow['siteName'] . "=:sid WHERE romID = :rid");
        $uquery->bindParam(':sid', $sid);
        $uquery->bindParam(':rid', $rid);
        $uquery->execute();
    } else {
        $uquery = $cbdbc->prepare("UPDATE roms SET " . $srow['siteName'] . "= '0' WHERE romID = :rid");
        $uquery->bindParam(':rid', $rid);
        $uquery->execute();
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to do a system where a user known as a ROM can be assigned 'sites' using checkboxes.

For every type of value except  pure numbers for 'siteID' (which is `VARCHAR(5)` on the MySQL table), e.g. `abc, abc12, 0001`, the value of `siteID` passes correctly and the value is updated correctly in the table 'roms'.

If I have a pure number as a value for `siteID`, e.g. `1, 15, 2339,` it will pass no value through `POST` and will always result in `0` being set in the 'roms' table.

I have tried making sure that at every step the value being passed is converted into a string, but this doesn't seem to help.

While typically site IDs are in the format `AXXXX`, I would prefer to see if this is fixable then force users to put in siteIDs of `AXXXX`, especially as this may change in the future to pure numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value **is not** the same as name or id. You can't send forms with only-number names, nor ids. Change your line to something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='yourUniqueId" . $srow['siteID'] . "' name='checkboxes[" . $srow['siteID'] . "]' value='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' checked='checked'>
```

Well, as you can see, your checkboxes are named now `checkboxes` and it's an array of data!! You can receive in PHP

```
$_POST['checkboxes']; // array(value1, value2, value3)
```

And you fix your problem.

Comment: Figured out a fairly simple solution. Changed the line to `name='id".$srow['siteID']."'`, now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Form field name must be a string. You can use this method:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='siteID[" . $srow['siteID'] . "]' value='0'><input type='checkbox' id='" . $srow['siteID'] . "' name='siteID[" . $srow['siteID'] . "]' value='" . $srow['siteID'] . "'><label for='".$srow['siteID']."'>" . str_replace('_',' ',$srow['siteName']) . "</label></td></tr>";
```

I change checkbox name like this `name="siteId[12]"`, and add hidden field (it`s not necessary).

After that siteID is an associated array of checked sites, where key is siteId, and value 1, if checked, and 0 if not.

```
$sids = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'siteID', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
while ($srow = $squery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $sid = $sids[$srow['siteID']];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I need the value that is being entered into the roms table to be the siteID

Comment: You can add it to checkbox value. I changed answer.